# Vb.net MYSQL foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am creating a system that requires the use of mysql. My tables are normalized to 3rd normal form but when I execute the code it does not write the appointment and tattoo table, can anyone see what I've done wrong. Here are my sql statements :

```
    SQLstring = "database=Tattooing_By_name;server=localhost;user id=root;password="

    tables(0) = "CREATE TABLE Staff " & _
                 "(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," & _
                 "staffname varchar(20)," & _
                 "StaffSurname varchar(20)," & _
                 "StaffcontactNO varchar(11)," & _
                 "StaffemailAdress varchar(40)," & _
                 "Staffpostcode varchar(8)," & _
                 "address varchar(40)," & _
                 "bio varchar(50)," & _
                 "username varchar(20)," & _
                 "Password varchar(20)," & _
                 "SecurityQ varchar(20)," & _
                 "SecAnswer varchar(20)," & _
                 "ResetCode varchar(15)," & _
                 "PRIMARY KEY (ID));"

    tables(1) = "CREATE TABLE Customers " & _
                 "(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," & _
                 "Custname varchar(20)," & _
                 "Custsurname varchar(20)," & _
                 "CustcontactNO varchar(11)," & _
                 "CustemailAdress varchar(40)," & _
                 "Custpostcode varchar(8)," & _
                 "PRIMARY KEY (ID));"

    tables(2) = "CREATE TABLE Tattoo" & _
                 "(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," & _
                 "StaffID int NOT NULL," & _
                 "CustomerID int NOT NULL," & _
                 "TattooDescription varchar(50)," & _
                 "PRIMARY KEY(ID)," & _
                 "FOREIGN KEY(StaffID) REFERENCES Staff(ID)," & _
                 "FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(ID));"

    tables(3) = "CREATE TABLE Appointment" & _
                 "(ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," & _
                 "TattooID int," & _
                 "Deposit boolean," & _
                 "Cost int(10)," & _
                 "PRIMARY KEY (ID),FOREIGN KEY (TattooID) REFERENCES Tattoo(ID));"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `s` in `Customers` table name when `CREATE ... Tattoo`

```
"FOREIGN KEY(CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(ID));"
```

or you should rename the `Customers` table to `Customer` :-)

Comment: Thanks, :P after stairing at it for the last 20 minutesit just looks like a red blob